# Generating and Storing Samples of an Exponential Distribution

Tags: python, loops, statistics

I've got a weird question for a class project. Assuming X ~ Exp(Lambda), Lambda=1.2, I have to generate 100 samples of X, with the indices corresponding to the sample size of each generated sample (S100, S200 ... S10000). I've worked out a simple loop which seems to generate the required samples, but calling different samples seems to post the entire list.

```
def sampleexp(x):
  samples = []
  for i in range(100,10100,100):
    samples.append(np.random.exponential(scale= 1/1.2, size= i))
  return samples 

sampleexp()
```

I've already seen a few of my classmates ask this question, albeit without any attempt to do the coding, so here's a college try at least. My loop generates the samples it seems, I'm just not sure how to make it so I can call individual samples from the list with the sample size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `list`, use `dictionary`:

```
def sampleexp():
  samples = {}
  for i in range(100,10100,100):
    samples[i] = np.random.exponential(scale= 1/1.2, size= i)
  return samples 

samples = sampleexp()
# then call by sample number
# samples[100]
```